# Как посчитать количество строк в объекте table html и записать его в последнею строку?

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, javascript-events

Есть таблица:

```
    @model IEnumerable<CollectVoters.Models.Friend>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

  <table class="table" id="friendTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FamilyName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>                
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FamilyName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>                    
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td>
               
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Нужно посчитать количество строк в ней и записать полученное значение либо в последнею строку, либо в др. отдельный элемент страницы.

Как посчитать разобрался, так должно работать:

```
<script>
    function cellCounter() {
        var trSize = document.getElementsByTagName('table').item(0).getElementsByTagName('tbody').getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
    }
    window.onload = cellCounter;
</script>
```

или

```
var tableSize = $("#friendTable").find("tbody").find("tr").length;
```

Как теперь вызвать и присвоить вычисленное значение либо в последнею строку, либо в др. отдельный элемент страницы?

Comment: Пардон, а почему бы вам не вывести просто `@Model.Count` в разметку, зачем эти javascript'овые танцы с бубном?

Comment: @AK, cпасибо! Я просто не знал, что так можно было )

Comment: @AK, напишите в ответ, я отмечу

Comment: Не конечно можно придумать сложную систему, когда записи интерактивно удаляются из страницы, при этом нет необходимости обращяться к серверу. Но в вашем случае я невижу надобности

Comment: Напишите самоответ, вам полезнее будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае можно использовать метод Count() объекта Model:

```
<tr>
   <td align="center">
     @Model.Count()
   </td>
</tr>
```